# Python Invalid Syntax on simple Maths Program

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I am trying to create a random maths question quiz but the colon comes up as invalid syntax. Is it due to the operator I can not use the colon? If I take it out it is also seen as invalid syntax.

This is the code to create the 'correct_answer' variable so if the users in putted answer is correct or incorrect it lets them know. If the whole code is needed (which I'm sure it won't be as this is probably something really stupid i'm missing) I can post it.

```
if operator==+:
    correct_answer=random_number1+number2
elif operator==-:
    correct_answer=random_number1-number2
else:
    correct_answer=random_number1*number2
```

FULL CODE:

```
import random

name=raw_input("Hi what's your name?")
print "Alrighty lets go, "+name+"!"

for i in range(10):
    operator_list=('+','-','x')
    operator=random.choice(operator_list)
    random_number1=random.randint(1,12)
    random_number2=random.randint(1,10)

question=1
print random_number1, operator, random_number2

if operator==+:
    correct_answer=random_number1+number2
elif operator==-:
    correct_answer=random_number1-number2
else:
    correct_answer=random_number1*number2


answer = eval(str(int(raw_input("What is the answer?"))))


if answer==correct_answer:
    print "Great job!"
else:
    print"Unlucky pal! It was " +correct_answer+ "
question+1
```

Comment: `operator==+`. That looks wrong. I don't know what it's supposed to be without seeing the rest of your code, but that's not right.

Comment: Give us more of your code to see where the user inputs a response

Comment: Of course that's a syntax error. You can't just put a + at the end of the line. What's that supposed to mean? Should that be a string? How is Python supposed to know here that you don't mean "Try to add == and :" or some other nonsense?

Comment: also i believe if it is a user input it should be `if operator == "+"`

Comment: `if operator=="+":` perhaps?

Comment: @Andy beat you to it :P

Comment: What kind of variable is operator? To compare strings you need quotations around what you are comparing. EDIT: apparently everyone beat me to this, check out DeliriousMistakes and Andy's comments.

Comment: `answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer?"))`; there's no need to convert it to a string and then evaluate it back to an integer.

Comment: Don't edit "CLOSED" into the title, please. Answer the question with what you did, or have someone else do it, and mark it accepted. Otherwise this question still shows up as unanswered to SO.

Comment: @DeliriousMistakes thank you man, knew it would be something stupid. Also thanks to everyomne else who said the answer, i tried it with ' instead of " earlier without success :(

Comment: @Basey No problem and as my professor always tells me "A stupid question is a question not asked"

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist better? :p

Comment: @Basey not what he meant he means just mark an answer as best and leave it you don't have to put closed.

Comment: @Basey and answer doesn't go in the question it goes in answer your own question should be at bottom of page.

Comment: @Basey Looks like you got some help from Delirious but yes. As soon as you can click the checkmark next to whichever helped you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `+` and `-` are strings. If so, you need quotes around them. It's also good practice to space out your code to make it more legible.

```
if operator == '+':
    correct_answer = random_number1 + number2
elif operator == '-':
    correct_answer = random_number1 - number2
else:
    correct_answer = random_number1 * number2
```

Comment: @le_wolfl Thank you, it was speech marks that were needed and I've done it now but thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER: All that was needed were speech marks around the operator.

```
if operator == "+":
    correct_answer=random_number1+number2
elif operator == "-":
    correct_answer=random_number1-number2
else:
    correct_answer=random_number1*number2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ans:

---

When you wrote + and - , python took it as a real for integer operator and gave it an error because there were no numbers. Adding ***" "*** will define it as a string and should not give a error.

---

Corrected version:

```
if operator == "+":
    correct_answer=random_number1+number2
elif operator == "-":
    correct_answer=random_number1-number2
else:
    correct_answer=random_number1*number2
```